# Entity Framework deleting object upon Update

Tags: automapper, entity-framework-core

I have a problem where Entity Framework (Core) is deleting an object upon update.  I think this is related to Automapper (map DTO Resource to object).  I have other objects mapped the exact same way as this object and updates work just fine.

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateFeedback(Guid Id, [FromBody] FeedbackResource feedbackResource)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    //removing or else get a tracking error with EF
    feedbackResource.FeedbackType = null;
    var feedback = await feedbackRepository.GetFeedback(Id);

    if (feedback == null)
        return NotFound();

    //if I use this line to map, EF will delete the object upon save.  

    mapper.Map<FeedbackResource, Feedback>(feedbackResource, feedback);

    // if I map manually, i get no error
    //feedback.Title = feedbackResource.Title;
    //feedback.Details = feedbackResource.Details;
    //feedback.IsGoodFeedback = feedbackResource.IsGoodFeedback;
    //feedback.IsReviewed = feedbackResource.IsReviewed;
    //feedback.FeedbackTypeId = feedbackResource.FeedbackTypeId;

    //if(feedbackResource.IsReviewed){
    //    feedback.ReviewDate = DateTime.Now;
    //    feedback.ReviewedBy = UserId;
    //} else {
    //    feedback.ReviewDate = null;
    //    feedback.ReviewedBy = null;
    //}

    await uow.CompleteAsync();

    return Accepted(feedback); 
}
```

I have no idea what to troubleshoot here and cannot see this issue on any google search.

Comment: You should start by adding a breakpoint to your code so that you can examine the result of the mapping operation and to ensure that all the properties of the FeedbackResource are bound and present as expected.

Comment: For me, this issue ended up being caused by an interaction between the automapper and EntityFramework. This was described well by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32120042/automapper-creating-new-instance-rather-than-map-properties

Comment: Impossible to answer this w/o a [mre].

Answer (score 5):

I was faced with a similar situation (ef core 1.1). I will assume that your problem is similar to mine.

[Also a similar problem is described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47334441/entity-framework-core-2-0-deleting-record-instead-of-updating-it)

I have the following models:

1) ApplicatonUser - standard user from EF

2) AnyDAL - any class in DB, which have link to user

```
 public class AnyDAL
 {
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

3) AnyDTO - model that comes from the browser side. Like your's `[FromBody] FeedbackResource feedbackResource`

```
public class AnyDTO
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public long UserId { get; set; }

    /// It is root of all evil. See below.
    /// And yes, it is bad practice.
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

Scenario:

1) get `AnyDAL` from the database;

2) map `AnyDTO` on `AnyDAL` using AutoMapper `_mapper.Map(DTO, DAL)`;

3) SaveChanges()

In one case, `SaveChanges()` leads to Delete, in other to Update.

What we should know: in my case property `AnyDTO.User` is always `null` after deserialization.

The choice between delete and update depends on the value of property `AnyDAL.User` before mapping:

1)`AnyDAL.User` is null - we get Update.

2)`AnyDAL.User` is NOT null - we get Delete.

In other words. If property `AnyDAL.User` changed from some value to null - entity will be deleted. Despite the fact that `AnyDAL.UserId` remains the same.

There is two ways to solve it:

1) Remove property `User` from `AnyDTO`;

2) Property `AnyDTO.User` should always has value.

Comment: I described my solution to a similar problem and indicated what exactly the problem was.

Comment: Yes, at first I wanted to comment but I can't do it because newbie.

Comment: Thanks, I had the same problem as describe in the question and your answer helped me resolve it.

Comment: I can't thank you enough! this solution worked for me I had the same issue

Answer (score 0):

This is a little old but I ran into the same issue with EF Core 2.2 and based on this 
[EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/16546) it is still an issue in 3.0

The issue seems to be that the navigation property being null is causing the entity to be deleted.

I was able to resolve by configuring lazy loading

Install this package

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies
```

Enable lazy loading in the configuration

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
```

Answer (score 0):

for me, this was resolved if I marked as Detached the entity, use automapper to map, then mark entity as Modified.

```
        _context.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Detached;

        _mapper.Map<ProductVM, Product>(viewModelProduct, product);

        _context.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;

        _context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had the same problem at this method in an UseCase of my company's code:

```
        private List<ElementoCronograma> UpdateAllCronogramaElementos(Cronograma cronograma, List<ElementoCronograma> elementosInputFlat)
        {
            List<ElementoCronograma> updatedElements = [];
            foreach (var elemento in cronograma.Elementos)
            {
                var currentInput = elementosInputFlat.Single(x => x.Id == elemento.Id);

                _mapper.Map(currentInput, elemento); // Here was the problem

                elemento.Filhos.Clear();

                updatedElements.Add(currentInput);
            }

            return updatedElements;
        }
```

Just found out that when transform the input elements into my database entity objects (ElementoCronograma), I I wasn`t setting the elementInput.Cronograma, only the property CronogramaId. For any reason, EF bugs and deletes it, even with the CronogramaId set.

The code with error:

```
        private List<ElementoCronograma> ToElementosCronogramasWithPaiIdAndFilhos(
            EditarCronogramaInput input,
            Cronograma cronograma)
        {
            List<ElementoCronograma> elementosInputFlat = [
                .. _mapper.Map<List<Marco>>(input.Marcos),
                .. input.Marcos.SelectMany(x => x.Arvore.Filhos).Select(_mapper.Map<ElementoCronograma>)
            ];

            foreach (var elementInput in elementosInputFlat)
            {
                elementInput.CronogramaId = cronograma.Id;
                // elementInput.Cronograma = cronograma; // this line didnt exist
                var parent = elementosInputFlat.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Filhos.Any(x => x.Id == elementInput.Id));

                if (parent == null)
                {
                    if (elementInput.Tipo != Domain.Constants.Enums.iPlanner.TipoElemento.Marco)
                        throw new ArgumentException("Apenas marcos devem e podem ser raiz");

                    continue;
                }

                elementInput.PaiId = parent.Id;
            }

            SetOrdem(input, elementosInputFlat);

            return elementosInputFlat;
        }
```

#### Additional observations

It's a pretty weird behavior, since when I am creating the related entity and when I am updating, we have so different behaviours

Creating: Dont even need to set it in the main entity collection, only refer it's id in the created related entity; (it's not even necessary to set the relatedEntity.MainEntity, only .MainEntityId) and also call db.Set().Add(relatedEntity) (or it won't work)

Updating: Don't need to dbSet.Update(relatedEntity), but need to update .MainEntityId and .MainEntity (and I found it out at the worst way possible lol)

Answer (score -1):

Entity framework needs to know if you want to update or delete. You need to solve this by giving the EntityState before `SaveChanges()`:

```
dbContext.Entry(yourUpdatingEntity).State = EntityState.Modified;
dbcontect.SaveChages();
```